# Ruby: How to populate subclass of Hash from Hash

Tags: ruby

I'm making a subclass of hash, which I want to be able to populate initially using a hash, i.e.:

```
class HashSub < Hash
  def initialize(old_hash)
    ...
  end
end

a = HashSub.new({'akey' => 'avalue'})

puts a['akey']

>> avalue
```

Since `Hash.new` doesn't take a hash, what's the cleanest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cleanest, in my experience, is to leave the initializer alone and to rely the class' `[]` operator:

```
>> class SubHash < Hash; end
=> nil

>> a = Hash[{:a => :b}]
=> {:a=>:b}

>> a.class
=> Hash

>> b = SubHash[{:a => :b}]
=> {:a=>:b}

>> b.class
=> SubHash
```

Comment: does this imply a dup or memory copy?

Answer (score 2):

To improve on Denis' answer, you can alias the class method `[]` to `new`.

```
class SubHash < Hash; end
  singleton_class{alias :new :[]}
end

SubHash.new(a: :b).class # => SubHash
```

Answer (score 0):

```
H = Class.new Hash
a = {a: 2, b: 3}
b = H[ a ]
b.class #=> H
```